# Google Analytics: Uncaught Type Error Cannot set property 'href' of undefined

Tags: javascript, symfony, google-analytics

I have added google tag manager on my page which looks like below

```
<head>
<script>
   dataLayer = [];
</script>

<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->

<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
    <noscript><iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXX"
    height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
</head>
```

Code is placed between head tags before I have declared datalayer as well, website developed using PHP Symfony, everything was fine except two days before, now all of a sudden I am getting error like

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'href' of undefined**

whenever the user clicks on any link of the page to redirect to other pages (error sample attached),

[Sample Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DRmG3.png)

Could not find anything of it for emergency purpose we have disabled the GTM container, If anyone has faced this scenario, Please suggest what would be the wrong case here,
Highly appreciate your time and feedback.

Comment: Where there any tags configured within GTM ? That does look rather like an  error in a custom HTML tag than a problem with GTM itself.

Comment: Eike thanks for your reply, you mean to say that some custom HTML tag configured in GTM account? And that causing an issue? Since I do not have an  access to GTM account I could not check i will get an access then I will post it here.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Can you please tell me more about custom HTML tag?